# Web App Bot Deployment incomplete (No route registered for /MSDeploy)

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

Creating a new Web App Bot within the Azure Portal leads to an incomplete deployment with the following error message:

Type Microsoft.Web/sites/Extensions

NotFound

"No route registered for '/MSDeploy?api-version=2015-02-01'"

I used the Question and Answer (QnA Maker) node.js template.

As a result of the incomplete deployment, no code for the QnA Maker template has been deployed to the corresponding web service. I downloaded the deployment scripts from the Azure portal and tried to use a different API version without success. The failure is always the same.

I also tried it with a different bot template, but the deployment was also incomplete.

Comment: That is odd. Could you share the app name and approximate UTC time where you saw this? Also, do you see this consistently if you create new apps, or was it just the one time?

Comment: It happend all the time I tried to make the deployment (few days ongoing before my post). Yes I did see this consistently, also for new apps. As the bot service is now generally available, I will try it again this week.

Comment: has this been solved ? same problem.